# Receiving a "Too Many Input Arguments" Error in my ODE Solver

Tags: matlab

I continue to receive the following error: "Error using symengine>@()0.0
Too many input arguments.", however the exact same ode solver and ode's are used in another piece of code I am running and I do not get the same error. I went through the entire code, line by line to try to figure out what is going on for more than 4 hours now and cannot figure out why this is happening. Any constructive suggestions here would be appreciated.

```
Error using symengine>@()0.0
Too many input arguments.
Error in bdipuniodefun (line 17)
bdip = [s(4); s(5); s(6); (q/m_e)*(Ex(s(1),s(2),s(3)) + s(5)*Bz(s(1),s(2),s(3)) - s(6)*By(s(1),s(2),s(3)));
(q/m_e)*(Ey(s(1),s(2),s(3)) + s(6)*Bx(s(1),s(2),s(3)) - s(4)*Bz(s(1),s(2),s(3))); (q/m_e)*(Ez(s(1),s(2),s(3)) +
s(4)*By(s(1),s(2),s(3)) - s(5)*Bx(s(1),s(2),s(3)))];
Error in odearguments (line 90)
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.
Error in ode15s (line 150)
    odearguments(FcnHandlesUsed, solver_name, ode, tspan, y0, options, varargin);
Error in collisions (line 195)
        [T,S] = ode15s(@bdipuniodefun, tspan, icv);
```

I have already went through the code, line by line and the error seems to stem within the bdip matrix definition. When I try to just run the function with the following direct input: "bdipuniodefunetest(1,[1;1;1;1;1;1;])" it still gives me the same error. What's really odd though is that when I do the same direct input with another piece of code that uses the exact same matrix and solver, it runs perfectly fine.

This may look like a lot of code but the other file where this ode solver and odes work, have about 300+ more lines. However, I know none of those additional lines have any influence on this error because they do not influence any of the inputs for the solver.

```matlab
%User inputs
%TSTEP MUST BE ABLE TO GO INTO TFIN AN ODD AMOUNT OF TIMES (Because simulation includes tstep @ 0 so it ends up being even)
tstep = 0.25E-7; %Defining time step
tfin = 3E-7; %Defining final time
ienergy = 1E-19;
%Initial conditions to solve for pitch angle and lambda value
lambdacheck = 60; %In degrees
options = odeset('RelTol',tstep,'AbsTol',tstep);
sine2alpha = (cosd(lambdacheck)^6)/sqrt(1+3*sind(lambdacheck)^2);
m_e = 9.11E-31;
v0mag = sqrt(2*ienergy/m_e);
vx = 0;
vy = sqrt(sine2alpha)*v0mag;
vz = sqrt(1 - sine2alpha)*v0mag;
x = 0.03;
y = 0;
z = 0;

icposition = [x,y,z];
icvelocity = [vx,vy,vz];

initial electron velocities, collision position, mfp and energy matrix will be saved
tic %Begin timer
%Create zeros matrices to populate later
intspan = [0:tstep:tfin]; %Total time span
intspancol = intspan(:); %inverts matrix's rows and columns
[introw,intcol] = size(intspancol);

%Generate matrix that will be populated by positions and velocities (Each matrix within structure "Wposandvel" should be of size 2*introw-1 by 6)
Wposandvel = zeros(2*introw-1,6);

%This section is purely for generating matrices the program will populate later
tindex = [0:1:introw-2];
tindexcol = tindex(:); %inverts matrix's rows and columns
[tinrow,tincol] = size(tindex);

for t = 0:1:introw-2 %complete time interval and time step

        [trow,tcol] = size(t);
        r = sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2 + z.^2);
    vmag = sqrt(vx.^2 + vy.^2 + vz.^2);

    %Coupled differential equation solver for trajectory within current time step
    icv = [x; y; z; vx; vy; vz]; %Initial conditions
        tspan = [intspan(t+1) ((intspan(t+2)-intspan(t+1))/2)+intspan(t+1) intspan(t+2)]; %Time span

        tic
        %Trajectory solver
        [T,S] = ode15s(@bdipuniodefunetest, tspan, icv);
        [rownum,colnum] = size(S);
        Wposandvel((1+2*t):(3+2*t),(1:6)) = S;
        toc

        %Redfine the velocity and position components to reference on next if-loop run
        x = Wposandvel((3+2*t),1);
        y = Wposandvel((3+2*t),2);
        z = Wposandvel((3+2*t),3);
        vx = Wposandvel((3+2*t),4);
        vy = Wposandvel((3+2*t),5);
        vz = Wposandvel((3+2*t),6);


end
```

```
function bdip = bdipuniodefunetest(t,s)

%Using SI units
q_e = -1.60217662E-19;
m_e = 9.11E-31;

persistent Bx By Bz Ex Ey Ez

if isempty(Bx)
    [Bx, By, Bz] = B_test();
end

if isempty(Ex)
    [Ex, Ey, Ez] = E_test0();
end

bdip = [s(4); s(5); s(6); (q_e/m_e)*(Ex(s(1),s(2),s(3)) + s(5)*Bz(s(1),s(2),s(3)) - s(6)*By(s(1),s(2),s(3))); (q_e/m_e)*(Ey(s(1),s(2),s(3)) + s(6)*Bx(s(1),s(2),s(3)) - s(4)*Bz(s(1),s(2),s(3))); (q_e/m_e)*(Ez(s(1),s(2),s(3)) + s(4)*By(s(1),s(2),s(3)) - s(5)*Bx(s(1),s(2),s(3)))];

end
```

```
function [Bx, By, Bz] = B_test()

Bfieldstrength = 0.64; %In (Teslas)
magvol = 3.218E-6; %In (m)
mu0 = (4*pi)*10^-7;
magnetization = (Bfieldstrength*magvol)/mu0;

syms x y z
m = [0,0,magnetization];
r = [x, y, z];
B = mu0 *(((dot(m,r)*r*3)/norm(r)^5) - m/norm(r)^3);
Bx = matlabFunction(B(1));
By = matlabFunction(B(2));
Bz = matlabFunction(B(3));

end
```

```
function [Ex, Ey, Ez] = E_test0()

syms x y z
R_s = 0.02;
V = 0;
epnaut = 8.854187E-12;
k = 1/(4*pi*epnaut);
Q = (V*R_s)/k;
r = [x, y, z];
E = (k*Q/norm(r)^3)*r;
Ex = matlabFunction(E(1));
Ey = matlabFunction(E(2));
Ez = matlabFunction(E(3));

end
```

The reason that bdip is all on one line is because the ODE solver actually solves the ode differently if I put it on separate lines (It does not compute the E-portion when I leave it on one line which is what I want for now)

Comment: Where exactly the error occure, in which line? On `[T,S] = ode15s(@bdipuniodefunetest, tspan, icv);`? Please post full error log.

Comment: Sorry @Karls I swore I posted it the first time around. I edited the main question to include it now.

Comment: I think the issue is more complexed. If you don't put all in one line (`bdip`), is the same error occurring?

Comment: Sorry for responding so late @Karls. I temporarily fixed the issue and it sort of came back again. It is not exactly the same issue though so I will start a new post.